Showing 4 images in each row for two rows while using Javascript For Loops to write HTML and CSS code
I am trying to have a page where I can have image selection, so I have used a for loop in javascript to write HTML and CSS but I need to be able to have four pictures on one row and four other pictures on another row and I can't seem to be able to. I've even added a div tag and use flexbox in css for that div tag and it doesn't seem to work. Could someone please help?
Here is my HTML with script in-line:
<script> 
let imgArray = [

             ["./img/Adventure.jpg", "Adventure"],
             ["./img/Girls Trip.jpg", "Girls Trip"],

             ["./img/Nightlife.jpg", "Night Life"],
             ["./img/Relax.jpg","Relax"],
             ["./img/Winery.jpg","Winery"],
             ["./img/Shopping.jpg","Shopping"],
             ["./img/Romance.jpg","Romance"],
             ["./img/Sport.jpg","Sport"]
      ]; 
 
      for (let i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {

        // create a new DIV
        let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv.class="divcell";


          let img = document.createElement("img");
          img.src = imgArray[i][0];
          img.style.width = "276px";
          img.style.height = "221px";
          img.style.margin = "10px";
          img.addEventListener('click', function() {
            if(img.style.border === "2px solid blue"){
                 img.style.border = "none";
                 return;
            }
            img.style.border = "2px solid blue";
          });

          newDiv.appendChild(img);
          
            let div = document.createElement("div");
            div.innerHTML = imgArray[i][1];
            div.style.margin = "5px";
            div.style.padding = "5px";
            // document.getElementById('imgContainer').appendChild(div);
            newDiv.appendChild(div);
            document.getElementById('imgContainer').appendChild(newDiv);

      }
     </script>

//Here is my CSS with script in-line:

.imgContainer {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;          /* Use flexbox to lay out*/
    justify-content: center; /* Center horizontally */
    align-items: center;     /* Center vertically */
    text-align: center;      /* Center text elements */
    flex-direction: row;  /* Stack children horizontally */
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: center;
    gap: 10px 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

Here is what I'm expecting the output to look like (https://i.sstatic.net/xFWvxATi.png)
Here is the actual result right now: Pictures stacked vertically (https://i.sstatic.net/CSWwWcrk.png)

It works fine if you use id selector #imgContainer.

Do you really want all those fixed px dimensions rather than a more responsive layout? Either way. look into using CSS grid which is more suited to specifying 2 dimensional layouts.

@Shuo thank you for your response. Sorry, that was my mistake. It works now though all 8 images are in one row. Could you suggest something to have 4 images in each row?

@AHaworth Thank you, I don't think CSS grid would work here as I'm using JS to write HTML and CSS and want the 4 first four images to be on the first row and the last 4 images to be on the second row.

I don't understand why creating the elementsu thro' JS would mean grid won't work. I'll put some code in an answer for you to check.

Thank you so much @AHaworth , your solution works!! :) I'm just a newbie, so I'm so sorry for my ignorance. Thank you for your kind help! :)

Here's a simple snippet, based on the given code which uses grid rather than flex.
Of course, there is more that can be done to make the result more responsive - not having such fixed dimensions for example, but this snippet is just to show CSS grid working with JS-created elements and giving 4 per row.


let imgArray = [

  ["./img/Adventure.jpg", "Adventure"],
  ["./img/Girls Trip.jpg", "Girls Trip"],

  ["./img/Nightlife.jpg", "Night Life"],
  ["./img/Relax.jpg", "Relax"],
  ["./img/Winery.jpg", "Winery"],
  ["./img/Shopping.jpg", "Shopping"],
  ["./img/Romance.jpg", "Romance"],
  ["./img/Sport.jpg", "Sport"]
];

for (let i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {

  // create a new DIV
  let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.class = "divcell";


  let img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = imgArray[i][0];
  img.style.width = "276px";
  img.style.height = "221px";
  img.style.margin = "10px";
  img.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (img.style.border === "2px solid blue") {
      img.style.border = "none";
      return;
    }
    img.style.border = "2px solid blue";
  });

  newDiv.appendChild(img);

  let div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = imgArray[i][1];
  div.style.margin = "5px";
  div.style.padding = "5px";
  // document.getElementById('imgContainer').appendChild(div);
  newDiv.appendChild(div);
  document.getElementById('imgContainer').appendChild(newDiv);

}
#imgContainer {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  /* Center text elements */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  align-content: center;
  gap: 10px 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
<div id="imgContainer"></div>




Thank you so much @A-Haworth - this is brilliant! Appreciate your kind help, sir! :)
